# Android support library, when to use?

Tags: android, optimization, android-support-library

I was wondering, lets assume I want to develope some android app and I need new API specifics but supporting some older versions aswell. The question is: do I build everything with support lib or do I check for sdk version everytime and according to this I run selected piece of code?
Best regards,
Robert

Comment: i guess it is better to build everything with the support lib instead of writing two pieces of code, one for the new and one for the old. though if you are sure that you will not be targeting older versions then in that case just use the new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the functionality that you need is available in support library, I would go for support library.

It will simplify your code, layouts, etc. a lot if you won't have to check for API version all the time. This means maintenance of your code will be much easier and number of bugs should also be lower.

Support library classes and usage are very similar to the actual classes so when you decide to drop support for older Android versions later on, the job of removing the support library will be fairly easy.